# Plotando arquivo .xls com matplotlib e openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, plot, xls

Tendo o seguinte conteúdo no meu arquivo .xls:

> Belo Horizonte - MG   2278.8
>
> Porto Alegre - RS     1647.8
>
> Recife - PE           2434.9
>
> Rio de Janeiro - RJ   1653.6
>
> Salvador - BA   2324.1
>
> São Paulo - SP   2227.5
>
> Total das áreas  14640.1

Como plotar os dados do arquivo .xls, tranformando-os em um gráfico(de qualquer tipo)?

Consegui fazer a leitura dos dados com o seguinte código:

```
import openpyxl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

book = openpyxl.load_workbook('planilha.xlsx')
sheet = book.active
celulas = sheet['A2':'B8']

for c1, c2 in celulas:
    print("{0:8} {1:8}".format(c1.value, c2.value))
```

Porém não sei como proceder.

Pensei em utilizar a biblioteca matplotlib, mas como disse acima, não sei proceder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que percebi acho que podes popular os valores dos eixos `x` e `y` da seguinte maneira:

```
...
y_vals, x_names = [], []
for c1, c2 in celulas:
    x_names.append(c1.value)
    y_vals.append(c2.value)
```

Podes fazer desta maneira simples o teu gráfico:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# apagar as proximas duas linhas quando o for acima popular estas vars com os mesmos valores
y_vals = [2278.8, 1647.8, 2434.9, 1653.6, 2324.1, 2227.5, 14640.1]
x_names = ['Belo Horizonte', 'Porto Alegre', 'Recife', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Salvador', 'São Paulo', 'Total das áreas']
x_pos = range(len(y_vals))

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15) # margem em baixo para que os nomes apareçam bem
barlist = plt.bar(x_pos, y_vals, align='center')
barlist[-1].set_color('r') # mudar ultima cor
plt.xticks(x_pos, x_names , size='small', rotation=35, ha="right") # definicao e disposicao das legendas em x 
plt.ylabel('km2')
plt.title('Áreas Brasil')
plt.show()
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]